# Standard Loop - wp_query

Tags: wp-query, loop

I was readind this article (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and try run the Standard Loop, but I can't receive the any result. My code is this:

```
<?php get_header();
/*
    Template Name: Page teste
*/
?>
    <?php
    echo "ola";
    // The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();

    get_footer();
?>
```

This code is on file call "page-test.php". Which is a template for a page on my WordPress.

Comment: where does `$args` come from?

Comment: Did you receive the "ola" message?

Comment: You don't have any query arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need some arguments defined.

A good place to easily get your loops defined is: https://generatewp.com/wp_query/

Here's an example of some arguments used.

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),
    'nopaging'               => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '3',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'    => true,
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```